# pthred_exit return variable static vs global scope

Tags: pthreads, static-variables, pthread-join

I am seeing different behaviors when variable used to get return values using pthread_join is defined gloabal vs static scope. I have included code_snippet here.

**Static variables**

```
int main()
{
 static int r1,r2;
 pthread_t t1, t2;
 int i1[] = {1,2};
 int i2[] = {3,4};

 r1 = pthread_create( &t1, NULL, myfn, (void*)i1);
 r2 = pthread_create( &t2, NULL, myfn, (void*)i2);

 pthread_join( t1, (void *)&r1 );
 pthread_join( t2, (void *)&r2 );

 printf("Thread 1 returns: %d\n",r1);
 printf("Thread 2 returns: %d\n",r2);

 return 0;
}
void *myfn( void *intarray )
{
 pthread_t t=pthread_self();
 int *g = (int *) intarray;
 int i=0;
 int d=1;

 for (i=g[0];i<=g[1];i++) 
    d*=i;
 fprintf(stderr, "TID=%u %d\n",t, d);
 pthread_exit((void *)d);
}
```

**Return value**

```
TID=3425117952 12
TID=3433510656 2
Thread 1 returns: 2
Thread 2 returns: 12
```

**Global variables**

```
int r1,r2;
int main()
{
 same as above
}
void *myfn( void *intarray )
{
same as above
}
```

**Return value**

```
TID=3425117952 12
TID=3433510656 2
Thread 1 returns: 0  <<<<< it returns 0
Thread 2 returns: 12
```

Could someone please explain why it behaves differently ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost certainly it's because the size of `int` and `void *` differ on your platform, so when `pthread_join()` writes a `void *` value through the `int *` pointer you gave it, it overwrites adjacent memory.

The different declaration of `r1` and `r2` changes the layout of the variables enough to change the effect you see.

Casting an `int` to `void *` in order to return it is messy; you're better off either allocating space for a result in the main thread and passing that to the thread when it starts, or have the thread allocate the result and return a pointer to it when it finishes.

However, if you insist on the cast to void method, you can fix it by passing the address of an actual `void *` object to `pthread_join` and then casting from *that* to `int`:

```
int main()
{
 static int r1,r2;
 void *result;
 pthread_t t1, t2;
 int i1[] = {1,2};
 int i2[] = {3,4};

 r1 = pthread_create( &t1, NULL, myfn, (void*)i1);
 r2 = pthread_create( &t2, NULL, myfn, (void*)i2);

 pthread_join( t1, &result );
 r1 = (int)result;
 pthread_join( t2, &result );
 r2 = (int)result;

 printf("Thread 1 returns: %d\n",r1);
 printf("Thread 2 returns: %d\n",r2);

 return 0;
}
```